# beautifulsoup raspar imagenes dentro de src

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup

Necesito raspar una imagen, pero estas no se encuentran en la pagina principal, como seria el procedimiento para poder realizarlo?

Les dejo la esctructura html, lo  que necesito raspas esta dentro de **< a href="/2021/12/131500.html">**

```
<table>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="impar">
                    <th>Fecha Local</th>
                    <th>Lugar</th>
                    <th>Magnitud</th>
                </tr>
                
                
                
                <tr class="par">
               
                 
                    <td>
                        <a href="/2021/12/131500.html">
                         2021/12/05 21:57:28
                             </a>
                    </td>
                    <td> 41 km al SO de santiago
                    </td>
                    <td>3.1  ML</td>
            
                

                </tr>
```

El codigo que tengo hasta el momento que obtiene todos los href del sitio, cabe descatar que las imagenes estan dentro de los link terminados en html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import urllib.parse
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
    
    
    e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')
    
    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print ("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que has intentado? Muéstranos un poco más y quizás podremos ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

deberías a la url base agregarle el path de la imagen y pegarle, ahi obtendrías el contenido de la segunda url en cuestión.

```
    import urllib.parse
urlbase = "https://www.ejemplo.com"
url2 = "/2021/12/131500.html"


print(urllib.parse.urljoin(url1, url2))
# --> "https://www.ejemplo.com/2021/12/131500.html"
```

Comment: gracias, pero no me queda claro como obtengo las imagenes